# How to set up the debugging of IronPython scripts within Spotfire Professional?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, ironpython, spotfire

I wish to set up the environment for example Visual Studio to make it possible to debug the scripts created in IronPython within Spotfire Professional.

Any suggestion how to do it ?

Comment: Are you sure that's even possible?

Comment: No. :) but isnt it good to ask if I am not sure? For sure you can debug the extensions in VS so perhaps it is also possible with this.

Comment: Of course it's good to ask. I just wanted to clarify whether you are sure it's possible and just don't know how to do it or whether you don't know if it's possible at all :-)

Comment: I still do not know how to debug scripts but I have found a partial workaround for this. What can be done is to open and analysis in Visual Studio that is setup for debugging Extnesions and this way it is at least possible to check how are the objects like f.e. base {Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.DocumentNode} = {Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Document} initialized by the tool. I find in helpfull so it is why I am adding this comment. Still it does not answer the question.